# Can i run html/Javascript files in IPAD

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ipad

i have a folder having an html in a folder and javascript files, can i run that html page without internet, just from file system and without internet, in ipad? Is it possible?

Also let me know, can i run some wamp like server on ipad to run html and php files?

Comment: is your iPad jailbroken? if not, there's no way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Serversman HD](http://serversman.com/) Try it out, it does both of the stuff you asked for and it's free.

EDIT:
It seems that someone answered a second before me, sorry for the duplicate

Comment: does not it have some english version?

Comment: The application is in English I believe, here is a link for the English version of the website:
[Click here](http://serversman.com/promo/promo_hd-ip_en.html)

Comment: Can i also run PHP SQLite on it?

Comment: I honestly have no clue, try to play with it and find out for yourself, if it can run PHP (which I believe it should) then it should probably be able to run all sorts of PHP extensions such as SQLite, you should just try to work with it and see if it can since all the documentation is in Japanese and there is no other way

Answer (score 1):

You can run a webserver on the ipad. See [this](http://serversman.com/promo/promo_hd-ip_en.html)
For local editing and previewing of files, there is http://htmledit.mediahive.com/
HTML Edit allows you to ->
**Work on files locally, with an optional base url and preview from the local filesystem.**

Comment: will my html and js files would run, also let me know can i run my php in it also?

Comment: See this too http://htmledit.mediahive.com/

Comment: I dont want to develop from scratch, i want to execute my html and js files.

Comment: There are apps from cydia (http://cydia.saurik.com/) available, php ,curl ,  lighttpd ,lighttpd sbs, but for these, you will need a jailbroken ipad (AFAIK)

Comment: Text, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, XML, can all be run by ServersMan HD. Host the server, and access the files locally...

Answer (score 0):

> i have a folder having an html in a folder and javascript files, can i run that html page without internet, just from file system and without internet, in ipad? Is it possible?

Yes. You have two main options:

- You can use [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) to turn static HTML/JS into an iPhone application.
- You can use HTML5's caching to allow a web site to run offline. http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/offline.html