# Store and browse static web content on a tablet (iOs and Android)

Tags: tablet

I wonder what the best solution is to store and browse static html pages with javascript, images and movie clips on both iPad and Android tablets?

The content is a product catalog and is rather large, about 2GB in size, and the idea is to be able to browse it offline.

According to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8312/how-can-i-can-open-local-files-in-the-default-android-browser) Android SE question, it should be possible on android with the built-in browser, however, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298420/can-i-run-html-javascript-files-in-ipad) SO question it seems like it's not doable on iOs.

I've also seen suggestions on making an application of html content using [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), but I'm not familiar with it so I can't tell if it actually is an alternative.

How would you do it?

**Update:** The package size is about 3,5GB (not 2 as mentioned above)

Answer (score 0):

Try the jquery API I hope there is a option to do operations like this

Comment: That doesn't answer the question about how to deploy and view the pages on e.g. iOS devices that cannot view pages from internal memory (without the need to buy an app).